# Not able to copy files from GCS in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to copy a file from GCS bucket to /tmp location in Dataflow. For that I tried the below code -

```
import apache_beam as beam
....
....
    class copyFile(beam.DoFn):
        def __init__(self, gcs_path):
            self.gcs_path = gcs_path
    
        def process(self, element):
            with beam.io.gcp.GcsIO().open(self.gcs_path, 'rb') as src, \
                open('/tmp/my_file.jar', 'wb') as dest:
                    dest.write(src.read())
            # Log a success message
            print('File copied to /tmp.')
            yield element
```

This code is working fine when I run using Direct Runner but throws error - `NameError: name 'beam' is not defined` when I run using Dataflow Runner. I don't understand the reason. Please can anyone help in resolving this?

Comment: Please share your beam pipeline code. It is hard to debug from the above code and error.

Comment: You probably need to use save_main_session=True. Check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#name-error

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is what XQ Hu suggests (`save_main_session=True`) but I would like to comment about how to read files in GCS from Dataflow. The code snippet uses the `GcsIO`module, and that's fine, but this could also be solved in a more generic way using the Beam filesystems module. With Beam filesystems, you could open files in a portable way in any storage system supported by Beam (local files, GCS, S3, HDFS, etc.).

That is, without having to change the code if you decide to move your files elsewhere. Another advantage is testing. With the above snippet you need to access files in GCS to test your `DoFn`. With Beam filesystems you could do unit testing using local files.

You just need to change `beam.gcp.GcsIO().open` by [`beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.filesystems.html#apache_beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open)

Comment: Hi @Israel Herraiz, I changed `beam.gcp.GcsIO().open` to  `beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open`, but it still didn't work as my beam pipeline just kept on running for 1 hr and failed with "JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed [installing the Apache Beam SDK](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/installing-beam-sdk#java_1) in your dataflow environment that is why you are getting the `NameError: name 'beam' is not defined`.

Looking at the `"JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR"` in your comment/ reply to Israel, it seems that your pipeline hasn't been progressing or there has been no worker activity for an hour, this can be linked to the missing Apache Beam SDK as well, it is failing because your code was not able to call the appropriate functions/ feature it needs to finis the job.